# Is there a way to integrate buddypress that it will not be overwritten when I update my theme to the new version?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Is there a way to integrate buddy press that it will not be overwritten when I update my  theme to the new version?

Comment: How is your theme laid out currently? Did you create child theme or modify the parent theme directly?

Comment: yes exactly the same..

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a WordPress [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and make use of the BuddyPress template hierarchy.

Ref: http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/template-hierarchy/